# Remove duplicate values that aren't on identical lines

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, sort, uniq

So I have a set of text that contains both the file names and an associated number. Currently it looks like this:

```
RR0.out -1752.142111    
RR1.out -1752.141887    
RR2.out -1752.142111    
RR3.out -1752.140319    
RR4.out -1752.140564    
RR5.out -1752.138532    
RR6.out -1752.138493    
RR7.out -1752.138493    
RR8.out -1752.138532
```

I want to write a script that will remove rows that are have duplicate second values. So that the output would be:

```
RR0.out -1752.142111    
RR1.out -1752.141887    
RR3.out -1752.140319    
RR4.out -1752.140564    
RR5.out -1752.138532    
RR6.out -1752.138493    
RR8.out -1752.138532
```

I have seen both `sort -u` and `uniq` used for this, but I cannot figure out how to remove lines that aren't exactly identical (which can be done with `uniq` but not `sort`) AND not adjacent to one another (which can be done with `sort` but not `uniq`).
Can anyone give me any suggestions?

So far the below code does not give me what I want.

```
sort -t ' ' -k 2n file > file2  
uniq -f 1 file2 > file3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sort -uk2 file
RR6.out -1752.138493
RR8.out -1752.138532
RR5.out -1752.138532
RR3.out -1752.140319
RR4.out -1752.140564
RR1.out -1752.141887
RR0.out -1752.142111
```

`sort -u` will sort the output and produce only unique values, `-k2` will do the sorting/uniquing based on the second column.

In order to reorder the output based on the filenames in column one you can pipe it back into sort:

```
$ sort -uk2 file | sort -k1
RR0.out -1752.142111
RR1.out -1752.141887
RR3.out -1752.140319
RR4.out -1752.140564
RR5.out -1752.138532
RR6.out -1752.138493
RR8.out -1752.138532
```

Comment: Technically you want `-k2,2` and `-k1,1` as opposed to your versions

Comment: @iruvar: That would make no difference, especially the first one

Comment: Yes in this case it would not, which is why I qualified my earlier statement with "technically".  `-k2` is sorting by the second field onwards, while`-k2,2`, which being sort by the second field only, is presumably what the OP wants

Answer (score 4):

If you're not insistent on using `sort`/`uniq` then:

```
$ awk '!seen[$2]++' file
RR0.out -1752.142111    
RR1.out -1752.141887    
RR3.out -1752.140319    
RR4.out -1752.140564    
RR5.out -1752.138532    
RR6.out -1752.138493
```

(It is different from your expected output since `RR5.out -1752.138532` and `RR8.out -1752.138532` differ only by trailing whitespace; `awk` treats this as part of the separator rather than part of the second field.)